# I'm facing antivirus restrictions on installation of python appium client

Tags: appium, python-appium

There error is:

```
PS D:\AppProjects\pythonProject> pip install Appium-Python-Client
Collecting Appium-Python-Client
  Using cached Appium-Python-Client-3.1.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  **ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error**
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
```

I want to to install it to use the appium. Please help to resolve it. I'm facing unnecessary restrictions.

Comment: Why do you want to install something your antivirus is flagging?  And if you're convinced it's safe, why haven't you turned off the antivirus?